# "zoom"/"scale" with coord_polar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I've got a polar plot which uses geom_smooth(). The smoothed loess line though is very small and rings around the center of the plot. I'd like to "zoom in" so you can see it better.

Using something like `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-.05,.7))` will make the geom_smooth ring bigger, but it will also alter it because it will recompute with the datapoints limited by the `limits = c(-.05,.7)` argument.

For a Cartesian plot I could use something like `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-.05,.7))` which would clip the chart but not the underlying data. However I can see no way to do this with `coord_polar()`

Any ideas? I thought there might be a way to do this with `grid.clip()` in the grid package but I am not having much luck.

Any ideas?

What my plot looks like now, note "higher" red line:
[image: Current plot, note larger red line, but its small.]

What I'd like to draw:
[image: What I'd like to get]

What I get when I use `scale_y_continuous()` note "higher" blue line, also it's still not that big.
[image: What I get with <code>scale_y_continuous()</code> note the blue line is now bigger and its still not that big.]

Comment: have you tried adding `ylim()` separately to the ggplot line

Comment: @mtoto Tried just now; as I expected it has the same effect as putting it in the `scale_y_continuous()` function.

Comment: Actually by comparing the source of `coord_cartesian()` and `coord_polar()` at github ([`coord_cartesian()`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/coord-cartesian-.r),  [`coord_polar()`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/coord-polar.r)) leads me to believe this may not be possible in ggplot2 itself as  `coord_polar()` doesn't have an argument to specify the limits as `coord_cartesian()` does, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't figured out a way to do this directly in `coord_polar`, but this can be achieved by modifying the ggplot_build object under the hood.

First, here's an attempt to make a plot like yours, using the fake data provided at the bottom of this answer.

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(theta, values, color = series, group = series)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 30*-6:6, limits = c(-180,180)) +
  coord_polar(start = pi, clip = "on") # use "off" to extend plot beyond axes
plot
```

Here, my Y (or `r` for radius) axis ranges from about -2.4 to 4.3.
[image]

We can confirm this by looking at the associated `ggplot_build` object:

```
# Create ggplot_build object and look at radius range
plot_build <- ggplot_build(plot)
plot_build[["layout"]][["panel_params"]][[1]][["r.range"]]
# [1] -2.385000  4.337039
```

If we redefine the range of `r` and plot that, we get what you're looking for, a close-up of the plot.

```
# Here we change the 2nd element (max) of r.range from 4.337 to 1
plot_build[["layout"]][["panel_params"]][[1]][["r.range"]][2] <- 1
plot2 <- ggplot_gtable(plot_build)
plot(plot2)
```

[image]

Note, this may not be a perfect solution, since this seems to introduce some image cropping issues that I don't know how to address. I haven't tested to see if those can be overcome using `ggsave` or perhaps by further modifying the `ggplot_build` object.

Sample data used above:

```
set.seed(4.2)
data <- data.frame(
  series = as.factor(rep(c(1:2), each = 10)),
  theta  = rep(seq(from = -170, to = 170, length.out = 10), times = 2), 
  values = rnorm(20, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)
```